# Error: Type mismatch: inferred type is Activity? but Activity was expected - Flutter

Tags: flutter

When starting the application I get the following errors in the console:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1
e: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_app_restart-1.0.0\android\src\main\kotlin\com\example\flutter_app_restart\FlutterRestartPlugin.kt: (55, 18): Type mismatch: inferred type is Activity? but Activity was expected

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':flutter_app_restart:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU�LD FAILED in 42s
```

How can I solve it? Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Goto the FlutterRestartPlugin.kt file and replace all the Activity with Activity? except package name and comment.

Answer (score -1):

This clearly seems to be an issue in the flutter_app_restart package that you are using. Maybe check the package's issue page for a solution [here](https://github.com/SachinBhankhar/flutter_restart_plugin/issues).

Also, that package seems to be a very new pakcage with no real documentation. If it is pragmatic restart of the app you are seeking, you are better off using something like flutter_phoenix package. You can find it [here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_phoenix).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).